# Create type from interface without property or list of properties

Tags: typescript, interface

I am looking for a way, given an interface like `Person` and a function like `something` that I can return part of `Person` without using `Partial`, because that makes any property optional.

```
interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  height: number;
}

function something(data): Example<Person, 'id'> {
  return {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 22,
    height: 5.9,
  };
}
```

I'm looking for a way for this to work. I tried `Partial`, `Extract` and `Exclude`.

Comment: `Pick<Person, Exclude<keyof Person, 'id'>>`.  If you need this often you can define a type alias `type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>`

Comment: // From T pick a set of properties K
declare function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K>;

Comment: reference link - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html